# Got an error while inserting the json string into snowflake table

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Trying to insert data to snowflake table

```
insert into realtime_kpi_feature_list_map (kpi_id, feature_list_id, config) 
values (1, 10, parse_json('{"b":1,"a":2}'))
```

but get an error

> SQL compilation error: Invalid expression
> [PARSE_JSON('{"b":1,"a":2}')] in VALUES clause

I tried with different json string but got the same error. What I do wrong?

Comment: You cannot use functions in a values clause, just literal values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works in my Snowflake environment...

```
    insert into realtime_kpi_feature_list_map  (kpi_id, feature_list_id, config) 
    select 1, 10, parse_json($${
      "b":1, 
      "a":2
     }$$);
```